# R visual sort order in Power BI

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

Not sure if this is the right place to request as this involves Power BI. Let me know if this is not the right forum.

I have developed a Power BI report with custom sort of geographic hierarchies. There are 4 levels and I have created the right sort order in the data tables. Using this sort order I have built 2 visuals, a Matrix table and an R bar chart. I used the R chart as I needed error bars and it is not available in other visuals. I am very new to R, searched the internet and I was able to build the bar chart with error bars.

My issue is the matrix table is working with the custom sort that I have built and is in the right order. However the R visual is in alphabetical order. I have searched the internet and was able to find code that will allow manual sorting of the items but this will work only if it is static. My chart is meant to be dynamic and the geography items change when I apply the filter.

Is it possible to get the R visual to follow the custom sort order that I have built?

Please see the screenshot below for more detail and here is my R code for your reference/review:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(unique(dataset), aes(x = LGA, y = Rate)) +
  geom_point(size = 5, stroke = 0, shape = 18, colour="brown") +
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = LL, ymax = UL), 
                width=0, position=position_dodge(.9), colour="brown", 
                alpha=0.3, size=4) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=45, hjust = 1))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image: R bar chart]

Comment: I'm guessing that LGA is simply a `chr` column in the `dataset` that is passed to the R visual and there is no information about the hierarchy. So, probably, you need to create a column that contains the sort-order and pass that also to the R visual, then you can sort the x-axis accordingly (there are many posts on stackoverflow that explain sorting of bars in ggplot).

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, the sort order column is from a different table that is linked to the LGA table via Relationships in Power BI Model. I will try to connect the sort order column to R and hope it will work.